# Read arbitrary line from CSV file

Tags: import, files-and-directories

Consider some large ".csv" file. For instance:

```
file = Export[NotebookDirectory[] <> "file.csv", RandomChoice[Alphabet[], 1000000], "TABLE"]
```

[image]

What is an efficient way to read an arbitrary line from this file? (`Import` uses up all my RAM and stalls my computer.)

## Attempt

I tried the following code involving `ReadList` but it wastes computation building a giant list. It is too slow for my (actual) purposes.

```
lineNumber = 987654;
Last[ReadList[file, String, lineNumber] ]
```

## Question

Write a program that outputs the $987654$th line from `file`

Comment: Have you tried opening it as a stream and using `Skip` then `Read` ? See also `SetStreamPosition`

Comment: By the way - it's a lot faster to generate that file like this `Export["file.csv", RandomChoice[Alphabet[], 1000000], "TABLE"];` instead of calling `RandomChoice` multiple times in a `Table`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of Mathematica are you using?

First off, the dataset recommended imports in 1.1 seconds on my machine:

```
In[62]:= file = 
  Export["file.csv", RandomChoice[Alphabet[], 1000000], "CSV"];

In[63]:= Import["file.csv", "Dimensions"]

Out[63]= {1000000, 1}

In[68]:= Import["file.csv", {"Data"}] // MaxMemoryUsed // AbsoluteTiming

Out[68]= {1.14441, 176206064}
```

But that said, if you have a much larger file than this example and still wish to extract only a specific row of data, this does so with minimal memory overhead and a very fast import:

```
In[67]:= Import["file.csv", {"Data", 987654}] // MaxMemoryUsed // AbsoluteTiming

Out[67]= {0.34555, 23767024}
```

It will properly address the CSV spec while only keeping rows requested in memory. Once the data is found it stops parsing. This syntax supports integers, lists, and spans.

Comment: Brilliant! `Import["file.csv", {"Data", 987654}]` works on my actual 17 GB dataset. Thanks. Btw I am using Mathematica 12.2